Looping sections with grouped values from model
I am attempting to place drugs under sections correlating to their class but I’m getting multiple sections for each drug I add of the same class.  I’m not sure how much this process differs when using model macros.
Current Result
List {
    ForEach(activeStash) { drug in
        Section(header: Text(drug.substanceClass)) {
            NavigationLink(destination: StashLinkView(stashed: drug)) {
                Text(drug.substance)
            }
        }
    }
}

Grouping but with duped sections Result:
List {
    ForEach(activeStash) { drug in
        Section(header: Text(drug.substanceClass)) {
            ForEach(activeStash) { drug in
                NavigationLink(destination: StashLinkView(stashed: drug)) {
                    Text(drug.substance)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Solution:
List {
    ForEach(Array(Set(activeStash.map { $0.substanceClass })), id: \.self) { substanceClass in
        Section(header: Text(substanceClass)) {
            ForEach(activeStash.filter { $0.substanceClass == substanceClass }) { drug in
                NavigationLink(destination: StashLinkView(stashed: drug)) {
                    Text(drug.substance)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


You need a ForEach that iterates over an array of sections and then within that another ForEach for each drug in the section

Grouping seems to work but still getting the duplicates of the same section...

“Solution:”, if you have resolved the issue then post the solution as an answer rather than adding it to the question

Your first ForEach needs to filter the available substance classes (the sections), the second filters drugs by their substance class to appear in the correct section:
struct Drug: Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let substance: String
    let substanceClass: SubstanceClass
    
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    
    var description: String {
        "Drug: \(substance) (\(substanceClass))"
    }
}

enum SubstanceClass: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case stimulant = "Stimulant"
    case sedative = "Sedative"
    
    var id: String {
        self.rawValue
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var substances: [Drug] = [
        Drug(substance: "Caffeine", substanceClass: .stimulant),
        Drug(substance: "Adrafinil", substanceClass: .stimulant),
        Drug(substance: "Valerian", substanceClass: .sedative)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Drug Store")
            List {
                ForEach(SubstanceClass.allCases) { substanceClass in
                    Section(header: Text(substanceClass.rawValue)) {
                        ForEach(substances.filter({$0.substanceClass == substanceClass})) { drug in
                            NavigationLink(destination: Detail(drug: drug)) {
                                Text(drug.substance)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Detail: View {
    let drug: Drug
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(drug.description)
    }
}

I made up the model from what was available in your question.
